# File upload 404 error on server

Tags: php, windows, server, http-status-code-404

I have a PHP file up-loader that we use to upload around 10-15 5mb images every day. I have the image uploader locally and i can upload images fine. I changed all the settings in my php.ini to ensure than i had the correct limits.

Now, i have put the up-loader on a windows server and it has the same settings, but sometimes (not always) when i upload 10-15 images it gets to 97 percent and throws a 404 document not found error.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this could happen? I have been trying to sort this for days it is really frustrating. I'musing php 5.6 on iis.

Comment: Did you restart IIS after making these `php.ini` changes? Sounds like an upload limit is still being reached (assuming by Windows Server you are using IIS).

Comment: Its strange though, when i hit upload limit in the past i got an error stating that, this is 404 not found.

Comment: That is how IIS operates, it'll return a 404 if the limit is reached: `(HTTP Error 404.13 - CONTENT_LENGTH_TOO_LARGE)`. You'll need to increase `requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength` (does the error log confirm this?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIS returns a 404 error when a POST length is too large:

> HTTP Error 404.13 - CONTENT_LENGTH_TOO_LARGE

You'll need to increase the file upload limit using the parameter:

```
requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength
```

Details of both of these items are on the IIS website:
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits

Comment: Thank you, i went in IIS and clicked the website then Request filtering > edit feature settingson the right then changed the max content length. This worked.

Comment: Fixed it for me, I couldn't find this anywhere

Answer (score 1):

For me it turned out to be neither of the PHP or any settings for maximum filesize setting in php.ini.

The IIS on the other hand limited the post upload size.

- To change go to your website in the IIS Manager
- Click on Request filtering
- In the right pane select Edit Feature settings
- Change the Maximum allowed content length to your desired byte length which is the maximum value (we used 100MB or 104857600 bytes)